# How to find the edge of list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a board game called Nip.
When player click cell I need to know if is it the edge of game board.

My game board looks like this
[image]

I'm able to detect which cell player click using floor function . However, I don't know how to judge is it the edge of game board or not using list like below

```
EMPTY,EDGE = 0,0
BLACK = 1
WHITE = -1

board = [
    [      2,     2, EDGE, EDGE, EDGE, EDGE,     2,     2,],
    [      2, EDGE, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EDGE,     2,], 
    [  EDGE, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EDGE,], 
    [  EDGE, EMPTY, EMPTY, BLACK, WHITE, EMPTY, EMPTY, EDGE,], 
    [  EDGE, EMPTY, EMPTY, WHITE, BLACK, EMPTY, EMPTY, EDGE,], 
    [  EDGE, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EDGE,], 
    [      2, EDGE, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EDGE,     2,],
    [      2,     2, EDGE, EDGE, EDGE, EDGE,     2,     2,],
]
```

I tried to look at the top, bottom, left and right of the selected cell and if at least one cell was missing I considered it as an edge. It didn't work well.
This is the function which checks is the selected sell is on the edge. row and col in code represents row and column of selected cell in board list.

```
  def is_on_the_edge(self,row,col):
        for drow in [-1, 0, 1]:
            for dcol in [-1, 0, 1]:
                if drow == 0 and dcol == 0:
                    continue
                check_row, check_col = row + drow, col + dcol
                if board[check_row][check_col] == 2:
                    return True
                else:
                    continue
        return False
```

How can I do this?

[This is my full code](https://github.com/igor-bond16/Nip/tree/main/Nip)

Comment: Show relevant code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. Relevant would be the code with which you tried to detect the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if `board[row][col]` is 2. This may or may not mean "edge" depending on your logic. If it isn't 2, continue with
2. `row in (0, 7) or col in (0, 7)` to check if the coordinates are at the border of the `board` square. If so, it is an edge, otherwise
3. check if `row in (1, 6) and col in (1, 6)` to cover the four edge cells in the diagonals. If this is true, it is an edge, if not, it isn't.